# Cannot see MinIO metadata in MinIO Browser

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, minio

I am able to upload an object to bucket successfully but when I add custom metadata along with object I don't find metadata in minio browser.

```
S3Client = new aws.S3 //config 
      var metaData = {
        'X-Amz-Meta-Test': "some-value"
    };
      S3Client.upload({
        Bucket: bucket,
        Key: key,
        Body: object
        Metadata: metaData
    }
```

Comment: It worked fine, metadata is added along with object but it will be not visible from minio browser.
To see metadata about object we need to use mc stat .